# :first-child targeting all child elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a unordered list with id of "navigation" and a few child list-item elements.

I am trying to select just the first item with `:first-child` but it is applying the CSS I use with this to all other list items.

```
ul#navigation li:first-child{
    background:#fff;
}
```

So, to reiterate: this is giving every list-item a white background. I just want to select the first element. What is going wrong?

Comment: Works just fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/HyKFJ/. Post your HTML.

Comment: I was about to do so, but realized that I am surrounding each list-item with a link. I want to keep it this way as I want the whole li to be a link, but that causes this problem.

Comment: @MarkLyons Don't surround your `li` with a link; instead set the links `display` property to `block`.

Comment: I achieved this with `ul a:first-child li` as a selector, but would making the link as `display:block` be best practice in this case?

Comment: @MarkLyons It would; don't wrap list items in anchors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the comments, your problem is that your markup looks like this:

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <a href="http://google.com">
        <li>Google</li>
    </a>
</ul>
```

Note how every `li` will be a `:first-child` under this model. I would suggest you go with the more appropriate structure of nesting your anchor within your list item. If you want the anchor to fill up the list item, set its display to block:

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <li><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></li>
</ul>
```

With the accompanying CSS:

```css
#navigation a { display: block }
```

Once you have those structural changes in place, your selector should target the first list item:

```css
/* > to target only immediate list items */
#navigation > li:first-child {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: This works, but adding `display:block` to the link does not make it effective throughout the entire area of the div.

Comment: @MarkLyons It's likely padding/margin on the list item are preventing the aesthetic you're after. Can you put your page online, or make a demo over at http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Yes, the li had a top and bottom padding. I added `width:100%` to the link and moved the padding to the link style. All good, thanks!

Comment: @MarkLyons You shouldn't have to set `width: 100%` on the anchor if you already set `display: block`, unless you have a previous width already declared for anchors to begin with.

Comment: I have a width for the list-items, but not the links.

Comment: @MarkLyons I see. Those too should be fine without `width: 100%`. If you remove their `margin` and `padding`, they will default to taking the full width of their parent, unless otherwise instructed.